# Unable to bundle all 4 scripts in one single bundle

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'am bundling my js files like below

```
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/important").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.globalize.js",
             "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.js",
             "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"));
```

'jquery-ui-1.12.1.js' is not loaded. if i just bundle that file separately it gets included.
How can i bundle all the 4 scripts in a single bundle?

```
public class BundleConfig
{
    // For more information on bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/validate").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery-ui").Include(
      "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.js"));

        BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
    }
}
```

when I am separately adding like this. it is working properly.

Comment: Change order,First you add "jquery-ui-1.12.1.js" then others

Comment: the client side validations are not working. form gets submitted without validations. @StephenMuecke

Comment: You can include as many files as you want. What make you think its not loaded?

Comment: `jquery-ui-1.12.1.js` has nothing at all to do with client side validation! The only scripts that are relevant for that are `jquery-{version}.js`, `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive`.

Comment: i want to add the scripts for jquery datepicker and validations in a single bundle.

Comment: Are you loading bundle  that contain jquery.js  first, then need to load this("~/bundles/important") bundle, because it has dependency with jquery

Comment: What you have shown will do that! If your code is not working then its because your code is wrong (show it)

Comment: when i am separately including the jquery-ui in a separate bundle, it is working properly. when added in a single bundle it is not validating.

Comment: @Ashita Is all the files at same path.

Comment: Again, `jquery-ui` has nothing to do with client side validation! It contains scripts for generating the html and the behavior/events for custom controls.

Comment: Change your BundleConfig as given below.Change the orders of files.

     bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(  
            "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.js",  
            "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js",  
            "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js",  
            "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.globalize.js"  
            ));

Comment: @VIGNESHARUNACHALAM, yes it is loading properly now.

Answer (score 1):

Change your BundleConfig as given below.Change the orders of files.

```
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(  
        "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.js",  
        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js",  
        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js",  
        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.globalize.js"  
        ));
```

Answer (score 0):

jquery-ui-1.12.1.js needs to be loaded first the other scripts need it.

Comment: None of the other 3 scripts have anything to do with `jquery-ui-1.12.1.js`!